# Connection to Azure Vault using MSI

Tags: c, .net, azure, azure-security, shared-secret

I am trying to connect to my azure vault from a console application with using MSI

For this vault i have added my user as the Selected Principle
the code i am using to connect is

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://<vaultname>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<SecretName>").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I get the following exception

> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException:
>   Parameters: Connectionstring: [No connection string specified],
>   Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority

[image]

Comment: Console app... running in Azure on a VM with the automagically generated service principal added to Key Vault's Access Policies? What do you mean by _i have added my user as the Selected Principle_, that's not how it works, the VM has its own SPN, use it.

Comment: I mean i added my AD user as a principle when setting up access policies in the azure vault

Comment: I am running the console app locally

Comment: What do you mean _locally_? The whole point of MSI is that it's implemented in the Azure resource. There's no mechanism in place for your **local** dev machine to acquire an access token.

Comment: Do i need to register my console app in azure? and use the applicationId and appSecret in the instance of the KeyVaultClient?

Comment: How can i use vault to get secrets from a windows forms app or a console app?

Comment: Yes, you need to register your app with Azure AD to get a client_id and client_secret. You'll then use those to acquire an access token for your vault resource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Enable Managed Service Identity in the *Configuration* blade under your virtual machine.

[image: Enable MSI in the virtual machine configuration blade]

2. Search for *NameOfYourVM* service principal and add it to your Key Vault under *Access Policies*. Add key/secret/certificate permissions.

[image: Add Service Principal to Key Vault]

3. On your Azure VM, run the console app.

```csharp
class Program
{
    // Target C# 7.1+ in your .csproj for async Main
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
              new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

        var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(
              "https://VAULT-NAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/SECRET-NAME");

        Console.WriteLine(secret.Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: Console output]

<s>To run locally, create your very own Azure AD application registration (Web App/Web API type to make it a confidential client), add it to Key Vault and use its client_id and client_secret when acquiring the access token —

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application#gettoken</s>

As [Varun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8722843/varun-msft) mentioned in the comments, there's now a better way to get an access token when running locally without exposing a service principal —

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication

Comment: AzureServiceTokenProvider allows use of developer Visual Studio identity or Azure CLI for local development. Please do not use Client ID and secret for this. The intent of MSI and AzureServiceTokenProvider is to not have developers deal with explicit credentials. Please refer this to use Visual Studio/ Azure CLI for local development. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication

Answer (score 4):

To run locally.

1. install Azure Cli
2. Open Windows Powershell
3. write `az login`  command (it will give an url and code )
4. Open Url and enter the code which is given with az login

then get the secret value like this

```
 var secret =  await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://VAULT-NAME.vault.azure.net/secrets/SECRET-NAME");
     secret.Value; //your secret.
```

Answer (score 3):

a correct answer is already given above, here's an additional one :-)

**Azure MSI applying with App Service & Vault**

1. Enable System Assigned Managed Identity for your App Service, check Identity section under settings.[image]
2. Add Policy under Vault
3. configure your code behind

   [image]